# How to use mongoose to return field from object array in string array

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a query in mongoose that return this:

```
{
    some_keys: "some values", 
    objs:[
        {name:"name1"}, 
        {name:"name2"} 
    ] 
}
```

I want to return in this format:

```
{ 
    some_keys: "some values",
    objs:[
        "name1", 
        "name2" 
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator loop through the `objs` array and return only the value of the `name` filed for every `obj`.

Try this:

```js
const result = await testSchema.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            objs: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$objs",
                    as: "obj",
                    in: "$$obj.name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "some_keys" : "some values",
    "objs" : [
        "name1",
        "name2"
    ]
}
```